# Tomcat 7 stops responding

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, ehcache

I have a REST (Jersey) web server using Tomcat 7 + Hibernate + Spring + Ehcache (as local cache).
The server randomly stops responding. I haven't captured (reproduced) the stopping behavior so it is hard to tell exactly when the server hangs. Once the server hangs, if I send a request, the request can't even hit the server (I don't see any request coming in from the application log file)

I understand it is very generic questions. But where do I need to take a look to find out more info?
After spending googling quite some time, I found out that I need to look at catalina.out log file and need to see the heap dump for possible deadlock, and JDBC connection, etc.

Where/How do I find out the heap dump? And where do I see any logs for JDBC connections?
I am using Spring + Hibernate and use transaction manager to manage the transaction. Is there any particular configuration I need to specify in the data source?

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to give any definitive advice with such a generic question.

Before going for a heap dump, I would start with a thread dump using the [`jstack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) tool found in a JDK install.
This could give you an idea of what your Tomcat is doing (or not doing) when it stops responding.